# PostgreSQL - Transform an INNER JOIN query to JSON hierarchy structure for frontend processing?

Tags: json, postgresql

I've got four tables in a PostgreSQL db.

`user` which holds information about a logged in user.

`project` which holds information about projects created.

`userprojects` as a joined table between users and projects (one user can belong to many projects and one project can have many users).

`timesheet` which is where users log their hours - has relation to `user_id` and `project_id` and people log their time and date in `duration` and `date` columns.

The `timesheet` table itself stores data as such:

```
id,   user_id,     date,            duration, project_id
1,     1,         "2019-02-01",      8,          1
2,     1,         "2019-02-02",      8,          1
3,     2,         "2019-02-01",      10,         1
```

I wish to find a nice way of returning the sum of values for each month from the `timesheet` table for easy frontend parsing and loading that data into a chart. 
What I'm looking for is something along the lines of:

```
{
        "users": [
            {
                "user_id": "1",
                "projects": [
                    {
                        "project_id": 1,
                        "sum": [
                            {
                                "august": 18
                            },
                            {
                                "september": 20
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "project_id": 2,
                        "sum": [
                            {
                                "august": 25
                            },
                            {
                                "september": 10
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
    {
                "user_id": "2",
                "projects": [
                    {
                        "project_id": 2,
                        "sum": [
                            {
                                "august": 40
                            },
                            {
                                "september": 100
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "project_id": 3,
                        "sum": [
                            {
                                "august": 30
                            },
                            {
                                "september": 25
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
```

I've found a neat query which kinda structures the data a bit, but still not ideally:

```
SELECT 
project.name,
to_char(date_trunc('month', date), 'YYYY') AS year,
to_char(date_trunc('month', date), 'Mon') AS month,
to_char(date_trunc('month', date), 'MM') AS month_number,
sum(duration) AS monthly_sum
    FROM timesheet INNER JOIN project ON timesheet.project_id = project.id
GROUP BY year, month, month_number, project.name
```

This query simply returns a table that looks something like:

```
name:       year:       month:       month_number:        monthly_sum  
Project XX  2019        Aug          08                     10,
Project YY  2019        Aug          08                     30,
Project YY  2019        Sep          09                     20
```

How would you guys go around formatting the `timesheet` table so I can easily display the summed value on a month by month basis?

Comment: you could write a postgresql procedure that would transform that data into JSON (using concatenation of strings for example), but I think that would be wrong engineering. You should rather use some sort of application as front to the database (you know a backend app) that exposes an API to your data for your frontend to consume it. Presenting the data is the job of the backend application. And you could use a GraphQL API so it would be easy and cool ! :)

Comment: Your desired output does not include year, only month - is that correct? Do you require to remove "Project " from `project.name`? How does output look for more than 1 user?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure what the output should look like, but just a nice formatted way that makes it easy for a frontend chart library to parse. The way the query spits out right now makes it too difficult to render. Some form of hierarchy is a good place to start..

Comment: I updated the post to better display the desired json output (or something within those lines)